# Displaying sub reports on alternate page in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report in the following order
Main report has 2 subreports report a and report b in the 2 details section detail-a,detail-b

the data is displayed as

column A,B,C (report a)

Column E,F,G (report b) (new page before checked)

All fields have "can grow" checked.

Problem no. 1

This works well if we have single page in both reports.
but with large amount of data it will show all pages of report a, then pages of report b
but I want it to print as 
A,B,C then next page E,F,G then next page A,B,C and so on.

Problem no. 2

Even if I am somehow able to display all records on alternate page and solve problem 1, there comes this issue that if any column out of A,B,C is of more height  and corresponding E,F,G are of single line then i want all fields A,B,C and E,F,G to be changed to same height. so that records per page of subreport-a and subreport-b will not only be same but also be of same corresponding height .

if you can give solution to anyone of the problems stated above, please tell .

Comment: a similar question but no solution yet 
[link]http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=18049

Answer (score 0):

You need to use paging to add new pages before or after your sub reports, split the sub reports into two details section and from section expert under tab called "Paging" check the properties "New Page Before" Or "New Page After" as your need.

```
shared numbervar lineCount;
lineCount > 25 //or whatever value you want
```

Comment: Thanks, but please avoid giving answer without reading the question brother, I already mentioned, I am using new page before.

Comment: Well i tried a lot but no idea how to use that, can you give further details.

Comment: @siddharthgupta i have updated my answer with formula